# Can anyone suggest some best practices for supporting partial representations in restful service

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I am implementing restful API where i would like the caller to specify the specific properties that one likes to be serialized something like `/dogs/1?fields=name,breed`. So if the dog has many more properties other than name and breed and I am using a standard serialization library like jackson how can i tell jackson to ignore the rest of the properties while serializing in runtime?

In other words what is the way to tell jackson to dynamically ignore some properties at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify version of Jackson library, so I assume that you are using 2.2.0 or newest. In Jackson this is not easy task to do but we can do it, for example, with [BasicClassIntrospector](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/BasicClassIntrospector.html). Below source code shows how it should look like. For example we have one POJO class:

```
class User {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    // getters/setters
}
```

We have to define new BasicClassIntrospector which returns bean definition object only with this fields which we need:

```
class ExclusionAnnotationIntrospector extends BasicClassIntrospector {

    private Collection<String> properties;

    public ExclusionAnnotationIntrospector(Collection<String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public BasicBeanDescription forSerialization(SerializationConfig serializationConfig,
            JavaType javaType, MixInResolver mixInResolver) {

        BasicBeanDescription beanDesc = super.forSerialization(serializationConfig, javaType,
                mixInResolver);
        deleteUnwantedProperties(beanDesc);

        return beanDesc;
    }

    private void deleteUnwantedProperties(BasicBeanDescription beanDesc) {
        List<BeanPropertyDefinition> beanProperties = new ArrayList<BeanPropertyDefinition>(
                beanDesc.findProperties());
        for (BeanPropertyDefinition bpd : beanProperties) {
            String name = bpd.getName();
            if (!properties.contains(name)) {
                beanDesc.removeProperty(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we have to create new ObjectMapper class with above introspector. We have to define properties we need in constructor:

```
class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper(Collection<String> properties) {
        this._serializationConfig = getSerializationConfig().with(
                new ExclusionAnnotationIntrospector(properties));
    }
}
```

And, finally, example usage:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BeanPropertyDefinition;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Tom");
        user.setSurname("Garnier");

        CustomObjectMapper onlyNameSerializer = new CustomObjectMapper(toSet("name"));
        CustomObjectMapper onlySurnameSerializer = new CustomObjectMapper(toSet("surname"));
        CustomObjectMapper fullUserSerializer = new CustomObjectMapper(toSet("name", "surname"));

        System.out.println(onlyNameSerializer.writeValueAsString(user));
        System.out.println(onlySurnameSerializer.writeValueAsString(user));
        System.out.println(fullUserSerializer.writeValueAsString(user));
    }

    private static Set<String> toSet(String... params) {
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String item : params) {
            set.add(item);
        }

        return set;
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
{"name":"Tom"}
{"surname":"Garnier"}
{"name":"Tom","surname":"Garnier"}
```

Comment: Thanks Michal for this detailed explanation. I assume my getter on my POJO will not be invoked if the property is an unwanted property which will give me better performance. Let me know if that is correct. One more thing is if the object mapper is shared is there an easy way to change this config so that other request are not impacted.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Unfortunately you have to create new CustomObjectMapper for each request, you can not reuse it. If this is a problem I can think about another solution where ObjectMapper can be shared between requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to take a look at http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/ 
(in particular section *Working With Includes/Excludes*)

Example:

```
    public String toJsonWithIncludes(Object obj, String...includes) {
            return new JSONSerializer()
                    .include(includes)
                    .exclude("data.*","*.class")
                    .serialize(obj);
    }

...
toJsonWithIncludes(obj, "name","breed");
```